# What is the meaning of "told" here...?

Tags: grammar, headlinese

Well, the full sentence is:
*Jeremy Corbyn **told** to 'sit down and shut up' in Commons as he criticises Iraq War after publication of Chilcot report*

I have the felling that the meaning of 'told' here is "someone told Jeremy something" but I don't see it.

1. It is a use of tell verb?
2. There is an imperative in past?
3. It is the past participle.

Thank you

Edit: [article source](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/jeremy-corbyn-told-to-sit-down-and-shut-up-in-commons-as-he-criticises-iraq-war-after-publication-of-a7122871.html)

Comment: You should include your sources and any other research you have done whenever possible.

Comment: @Max Sorry. You are right. The source is http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/jeremy-corbyn-told-to-sit-down-and-shut-up-in-commons-as-he-criticises-iraq-war-after-publication-of-a7122871.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an example of [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese). A common abbreviation found in headlines is

> Forms of the verb "to be" are omitted.

I believe [this](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/jeremy-corbyn-told-to-sit-down-and-shut-up-in-commons-as-he-criticises-iraq-war-after-publication-of-a7122871.html) is the article. We notice that "was" was omitted:

> Jeremy Corbyn **was** told to 'sit down and shut up' in Commons as he criticises Iraq War after publication of Chilcot report

So, yes, someone told him to "sit down and shut up". I believe this is passive.

Comment: Yes it is. That's the article. It's very interesting that writing style. Thankyou!